# How do i keep changes on a page after navigation away from it

Tags: nativescript

I have this page with two buttons as shown below. The goal is to fire an event that changes the color of the button ontap.

The problem is that after the tap event changes the color and i navigate away from it the color of the buttons returns back to default.

Please how do i keep the changes after navigation away?

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded" navigatedTo="navigatedTo">

<ActionBar title="Settings">
  <NavigationButton text="Back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" tap="homeTap"/>
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">

    <Button class="optionOne" text="option one" tap="optionOneTap"> </Button>
    <Button class="optiontwo" text="option two" tap="optionTwoTap"> </Button>  


</StackLayout>
</Page>
```

the javascript code:

```
var orientation = require('nativescript-orientation');
var page = require("ui/page");
var button = require("ui/button");

exports.pageLoaded = function (args) {
    page = args.object;
}


exports.navigatedTo = function () {
    orientation.setOrientation("portrait");
}   


exports.optionOneTap = function () {
    page.addCss(".optionOneTap {background-color: red}")
}  

exports.optionTwoTap = function () {
    page.addCss(".optionTwoTap {background-color: blue}")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved this. What needs to be accomplished is to kind of... save state of the button pressed so the user can know on navigating back to the page and be able to know what he previously pressed or entered.

When user pressed any button perform the action:

```
exports.optionOneTap = function () {
    //save the number to app settings, u will use this later
    applicationSettings.setNumber("numberSaved", 1);
    page.addCss(".optionOneTap {background-color: red}")

} 

exports.optionTwoTap = function () {
    //save number again, u sill need  it later
    applicationSettings.setNumber("numberSaved", 2);
    page.addCss(".optionTwoTap {background-color: blue}")
}
```

Now create a private function:

```
function getButtonColorState () { //name it whatever you want
    var buttonPressed = applicationSettings.getNumber("numberSaved"); 
    if (buttonPressed === 1) {
        page.addCss(".optionOneTap {background-color: red}")
    }
    else if (buttonPressed === 2) {
        page.addCss(".optionTwoTap {background-color: blue}")
    }
}
```

finally, call this function when the page loads or on navigation to page.

```
exports.pageLoaded = function (args) {
    page = args.object;
    getButtonColorState();
}
```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static class to keep the state; something like

```
export class AppState {
    static state = {
          //some properties
    };
}
```

Or use this plugin: http://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/application-settings

```
var appSettings = require("application-settings");

appSettings.setString("lastColor", "blue");
var stringValue = appSettings.getString("lastColor");
```

Comment: page.addCss(".optionone {background-color: stringValue)}"). it does not seem to be able to read from a variable.

Comment: you shouldn't put the css definition there.  just put the class name without dot and specify the class somewhere else.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. i have to store the appSettings.getString in variable. Now to use it in page.addCss(). Only that page.addCss does not read from a variable.